# Build and reload in RStudio generates 'Save File' error

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools

I'm working on an Rcpp-enabled R package as a project in RStudio (version 1.0.136, Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit), and have recently started getting an error after building the package with Tools > Build and Reload. The error dialogue box reads:

```
Save File
No such file or directory
```

The error doesn't appear straight after building and reloading. Rather, it occurs some time later while making edits to files, seemingly at random, and not necessarily while trying to save. However, after closing the dialogue box files cannot be saved without generating another error, this time with the message:

```
Error Saving File
No such file or directory
```

Following that, the only way forward is to restart RStudio without saving any files, thus losing all changes.

It doesn't seem to be a problem with either roxygen2 or devtools since I've tried building with and without the *Generate documentation with Roxygen* and *Use devtools package functions* options in Tools > Project Options > Build Tools. I've also tried uninstalling andreinstalling RStudio as well as updating devtools etc, but the problem persists. I'm wondering if it's an issue in one of the package files such as NAMESPACE or DESCRIPTION. The package repository is available at https://github.com/shaunpwilkinson/insect.

Comment: Not an _Rcpp_ problem. The problem is directly related to the _RStudio_ IDE. Specifically, the file pointer seems to be corrupted. I've run into this problem as well.

Comment: Thanks @coatless - I ended up just creating a new package and copying all the code across. For interest's sake I compared the contents and found the corrupted package was missing the lock_file and it's parent directory within .Rproj.user/BD026F6/sdb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into this error myself, and I'm posting what seems to have worked based on the comment from Shaun and a post on the RStudio support website.

The error is not limited to building a package; I encountered it while working in a bog standard RStudio project.

I found this comment from RStudio support [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200661597-Saving-Error-No-such-file-or-directory-):

> I think that if you clear the sdb (source data based) directory inside ~/.rstudio, then this might get things working for now.

So I closed RStudio, went into the terminal and removed the entire subdirectory .RStudio.user (inside the project directory, which is not what the comment above suggested directly). I restarted RStudio and voila. It works, and RStudio recreated the .RStudio.user directory.

WARNING: this **will** delete all the unsaved data including the contents of your environment and any unsaved files. You should copy the contents of unsaved files to another text editor before using this fix.

For future reference I am using RStudio 1.0.143 on OS/X 10.12.5.

Comment: Just to add a quick note: Deleting `.Rproj.user` will result in the loss of data that is not directly saved (i.e., the current environment, the history, and unsaved skripts)... But it resolved the error for me.

Comment: Yikes, hope you didn't loose too much. I will add a warning to the answer.

Comment: @atiretoo has there been any updates on this issue released by RStudio? I'm running into this problem currently, and deleting the .RStudio directory is not doing the trick unfortunately

Comment: I haven’t checked with RStudio. But using recent versions I have not run into the error either (1.1.38?)

Answer (score 1):

As per [1]: This usually implies that, for some reason, your user account does not have write permissions to the folder at ~/.rstudio-desktop (or ~/.rstudio for RStudio Server).

Solution:

sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.rstudio*

[1] https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2037

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem however could not find the mentioned sdb directory. Might be very obvious but just nuking everything and re-installing also works. I suffered a lot from this kind of problems when I was a beginner and didnt really understand what I was supposed to do in many cases so here is all steps in case any beginner ends up here:

First uninstall R. Then on terminal

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.rstudio
sudo rm ~/.Rhistory # probably redundant
```

Then reinstall it again.