# R server Error Saving File No such file or directory (Ubuntu)

Tags: r, ubuntu, permissions, save, rstudio

This question is similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42501779/build-and-reload-in-rstudio-generates-save-file-error), but the response there doesn't really give what I need.

**Context**:
After I edit the R script on RStudio, it pops out an error message and says: "Error Saving File: No such file or directory". At the same time, I can't open any script also (error message: "Error while opening file: no such file or directory". (a permissions issue?)

I've been having this problem for a while now, and the solution from other posts doesn't seem to work for my situation. Including:

- clear the sdb (source data based) directory inside ~/.rstudio ([Rstudio support](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200661597-Saving-Error-No-such-file-or-directory-))
- deleting ~/.rstudio and restart the R session ([Rstudio support](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115006836127--No-such-file-or-directory-RStudio-Server-error))
- sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.rstudio* ([Github](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2037))

I'm using R server (1.1.423) with Microsoft Azure on Ubuntu 16.04.3 xenial.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] stringr_1.1.0     haven_1.1.1       dplyr_0.5.0       zoo_1.8-1         readxl_1.0.0      RODBC_1.3-15     
 [7] lubridate_1.7.3   svMisc_1.0-2      data.table_1.10.0 rstudioapi_0.7   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.13     lattice_0.20-35  assertthat_0.1   R6_2.2.2         grid_3.4.3       cellranger_1.1.0
 [7] DBI_0.5-1        magrittr_1.5     stringi_1.1.2    forcats_0.3.0    tools_3.4.3      compiler_3.4.3  
[13] tibble_1.2

> RStudio.Version()
$citation

To cite RStudio in publications use:

  RStudio Team (2016). RStudio: Integrated Development for R. RStudio, Inc., Boston, MA URL
  http://www.rstudio.com/.

A BibTeX entry for LaTeX users is

  @Manual{,
    title = {RStudio: Integrated Development Environment for R},
    author = {{RStudio Team}},
    organization = {RStudio, Inc.},
    address = {Boston, MA},
    year = {2016},
    url = {http://www.rstudio.com/},
  }


$mode
[1] "server"

$version
[1] ‘1.1.423’
```